# The attached property is not send to the style

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I wanted to create a cell style to show errors and a text with the tooltip.

My style in the xaml dictionary file is this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DataGridCellConErrores">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="5000"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="60000"/>

    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=dlgEnviarAlbaranCantidadParaDescontarTooltipMultivalueConverter}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding Path="(ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip01)"/>
                    <Binding Path="(ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip02)"/>
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.EsDatoCorrecto)}" Value="false"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This is how I am trying to use in my column of the datagrid:

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cantidad Para Descontar" Binding="{Binding CantidadParaDescontar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="AUTO" IsReadOnly="false"
                            ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip01="{Binding Path=DescripcionCantidadParaDescontar}"
                            ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip02="{Binding Path=MotivoCantidadParaDescontarIncorrecta}"
                            ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.EsDatoCorrecto="{Binding Path=EsCantidadParaDescontarCorrecta}"
                            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellConErrores}"/>
```

I can compile and run, but the text of tooltip is always empty and also it doesn't change the color of the background if the data is not correct.

How should I bind the attached properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Binding with only a Path uses the current DataContext as source object. You are however setting the attached properties on the DataGridTextColumn. In case that is a parent element of the styled DataGridCells (not sure about that), you would have to add `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncstorType=DataGridTextColumn}"` to the Bindings.

Comment: I have tried ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip01="{Binding Path=DescripcionCantidadParaDescontar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridTextColumn}}", but the converter still gets the unsetvalue.

Comment: The RelativeSource was meant to be added to the Bindings in the MultiBinding.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this: <Binding Path="(ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip01)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridTextColumn}"/> but I get the same result.

Comment: As said, I do not know whether the DataGridTextColumn is actually an ancestor of the DataGridCell. Maybe it isn't.

Comment: It is possible it is not the ancestor, I will try with another possible ancestors. And thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind to the attached property of the column. Try this:

```
<Binding Path="Column.(ap:CeldasDatagridConErroresAttachedProperty.TextoTooltip01)"/>
```